# At first time loading Give id (same as date ) of Image which is add before each date in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using 'Arshaw's Fullcalendar'. I had added image before each date but i can not give id of image which is same as date,more i want to open  a popup form whenever click on image then and then only popup need to open. Please friends if u have solution of this kind of problem then please share with me

Here u can see count variable which is need to take  because whenever i will change the view then image is append more 1 or 2 time before each date so please i want image only 1 time add so please check this issue also

---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count=0;
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventRender: function( event, element, view, start){
                //alert("New EventRender");
                if(count==0){
                    $(".fc-day-number").before("<img src='/assets/images/add2.png' style='' name='date' id='+data-date'>");
                    alert(count);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put some effort in writing your question. Review the post and use proper punctuation and capital letters.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but will u provide me answer then it is very useful for me

Comment: dont want to extend such meta discussion but we might not feel too compeled to answer what is difficult to understand as dont really like put much effort when you just cast doubt on your intention to ease our effort to understand you and your question and if you have some problem what the problem is in case you need help which we dont really understand what it is but not because lack of english skills or grammar but just separate sentences and put some logic order on them because we need to understand you better to answer usefully

Comment: now did you get my question?